# How to fix 'no entitymanager with actual transaction' when deleteallby method gets called?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a spring boot back-end and want to make a rest end-point, that deletes all item by the suppliers id. When I call the rest end-point, I get 'no entitymanager with actual transaction available' exception.

How can I fix this error?

I tried the `@Transactional` annutation, but the error still occurs

Model:

```
public class Item {

    public Item() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ItemId")
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.id = Id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Suppid")
    private int suppid;
    public int getSuppid() {
        return this.suppid;
    }
    public void setSuppid(int Suppid) {
        this.suppid = Suppid;
    }  
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {
    @Transactional
    public void deleteAllBySuppid(int suppid);
}
```

Controller:

```
public void deleteSupplier(@RequestParam(name = "suppid") int suppid) {

    itemrepo.deleteAllBySuppid(suppid);
    supprepo.delete(supprepo.findByid(suppid));
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expect the item to be deleted, but it throws:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'remove' call] with root cause
```

Comment: Put that logic in a service method annotate that method with `@Transactional`. That is business logic and belongs in the service layer not the web layer.

Comment: Have you even configured an `EntityManager`?

Comment: as @M.Deinum has said, you must put the logic into a service class, an annotate it with {@transactional}

Comment: @M.Deinum, I apologize for not answering your comment as quickly as I could, but thank you for giving me a hint for the solution. I placed the annotation to the method. I know, I don't have a service or multiple services, but this back-end is a part of my school project. I am a beginner at making back-end programms with spring boot and I hadn't had the time yet to read about services, because I wanted it to keep the code easy. But for self-education, I am taking your advice to putting all the business logic in services in the future. Thank you a lot for the help.

Comment: You really should have a service layer/facade. You don;t want your web-layer to be the transactional boundary.

Answer (score 3):

To explain why `@Transactional` is needed:

Whan you look at the `CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.postProcess` method, all Methods contained in the `implementations` set are called with the `TransactionSynchronizationManager`. Custum Functions need to add Transactions manually.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was my mistake, because I put the `@Transactional` at the wrong place. I had to put the annutation on the method in my controller, not in the CrudRepository.

Repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {

    public void deleteAllBySuppid(int suppid);
}
```

Controller:

```
@Transactional
public void deleteSupplier(@RequestParam(name = "suppid") int suppid) {

    itemrepo.deleteAllBySuppid(suppid);
    supprepo.delete(supprepo.findByid(suppid));
}
```

Comment: Creating a service and adding it there would be better

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, but the the `@Transactional` annotation didn't solve it.

I had a strange problem: I didn't add `@SpringBootApplication` to my Main class. Adding this annotation solved my problem.